# Save data from for loop within program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

Say, I have an application log file, which is increasing line by line

```
Jan 13 20:44:25 Think process1: ID1: Request received user=user1
Jan 13 20:44:26 Think process1: ID2: Request received user=user2
Jan 13 20:44:27 Think process2: ID1: user accessed file=file1
Jan 13 20:44:28 Think process1: ID3: Request received user=user3
Jan 13 20:44:29 Think process3: ID1: Request Served token=tok1
Jan 13 20:44:30 Think process2: ID2: user accessed file=file2
Jan 13 20:44:31 Think process3: ID2: Request Served token=tok2
Jan 13 20:44:32 Think process2: ID3: user accessed file=file3
.....
Jan 13 20:59:24 Think process3: ID**N**: user accessed file=file**N**
```

And my code is as follows

```
from sh import tail

def received(input_message):
    user1 = input_message[2].split('=')
    user = user1[1].replace('\n', '')
    return(user)

def accessed(input_message):
    file1 = input_message[2].split('=')
    file = file1[1].replace('\n', '')
    return(file)

def served(input_message):
    tok1 = input_message[2].split('=')
    tok = tok1[1].replace('\n', '')
    return(tok)

for line in tail("-f", "/opt/jagan/app.log", _iter=True):
    column = line.split(' ')
    date = column[0] + ' ' + column[1] + ' ' + column[2]
    host = column[3]
    process = column[4]
    ID = column[5]
    message = column[6:]
    if "process1" in process:
         username = received(message)
         print("Username is:" +(username))
    if "process2" in process:
         filename = accessed(message)
         print("filename is:" +(filename))
    if "process3" in process:
         token = served(message)
         print("Token is:" +(token))
```

In this, ID is unique for every request. And it will go through all the processes.
So when a one request is completed, I want to print all the required data when a request is served.

Like:

```
>['user1','file1','tok1']
['user**N**','file**N**','tok**N**']
```

QUESTION 1. How to store data from `for` loop, within the program? I don't to store data in a file or some DB. Because, logs generation will be too high, it will effect this program performance.

QUESTION 2. How to trigger an action with all the data of a request, when a request is completed? I want to trigger an action, when a request is completed, all the information of the request. say I want to create variable lists with variable data and also don't want to save data somewhere else. And if the program stops, data will also be lost (I am OK with this).

Comment: QUESTION 1. Like in a variable?

QUESTION 2. Outputs the variable from question 1 ?

Comment: @JagannathNaidu Did you try to run the code? because it has some errors...

Comment: @OferArial: process1, process2 and process3, Enclose within quotes, as these are strings. Correct the spelling from reveived to received. I've corrected the code. Check again, it will work fine

Comment: @JulienB.: Yes, like in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
logs=[]
for line in tail...
    ...
    logs.append([filename, username, token])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

To save the wanted data, you can use a dictionary or a list, whenever served is called (if I understand correctly, that is the last stage of your data saving code).

You should specify a `global scope` variable, that will save it:

**Example:**

```
data_list = []
data_dict = {} # Use the ID as a key, and all values of data as the value
```

**Question 2:**

If you want to perform a `function`(action) with your recieved data, call a function with the data as arguments when you are finished to collect your data (again, when served is called):

**Example:**

```
def parse_data(line):
    pass # Your parsing code

# And your function call
for line in tail("-f", "/opt/jagan/app.log", _iter=True):
...
if "process3" in process:
     token = served(message)
     parse_data(line)
     print("Token is:" +(token))
...
```

Comment: But my incoming data is not ordered.   *Jan 13 20:44:25 Think process1: ID1: Request received user=user1*,         *Jan 13 20:44:26 Think process1: ID2: Request received user=user2*. I.e, **ID1:process1,ID1,process2,ID2:process1,ID2:process2,ID:process3,ID1:process3.** In this case, how to serve data of request one.

Comment: CORRECT:   But my incoming data is not ordered.   *Jan 13 20:44:25 Think process1: ID1: Request received user=user1*,         *Jan 13 20:44:26 Think process1: ID2: Request received user=user2*. I.e, **ID1:process1,ID1:process2,ID2:process1,ID2:process2,ID2:process3,ID1:process3.** In this case, how to serve data of request one (ID1) after serving requesting two (ID2).

Comment: @JagannathNaidu It's not complicated. The order in logs must be correct, so when the "process3" of ID2 will come, data of ID2 will be parsed, and when "process3" of ID1 will come, data of ID1 will be parsed. It will happen the way you want

Comment: Condition is order can not be correct. Please share code if possible. Thanks anyhow. Found that it can be achieved, so proceeding with using external database.